# Microsoft Bot Framework Suggested Actions - Allow Editing Text

Tags: botframework

Currently I create suggested actions using the 'imBack' type. When the user clicks on a suggested action, they effectively send a message to the bot as if they had typed out the suggested action's message themselves and pressed enter.

My users are asking if it is possible to allow them to edit the text of the suggested action first, and only then send it to the bot.

The suggested actions in my application are long (up to two sentences) so ideally the user want a shortcut instead of having to type in the entire message corresponding to the action if they only want to edit a word or two.

One way this could work is that instead of sending the action when clicked, the action's message would instead be copied into the message input area where the user can modify the text and then send manually.

Another way is to allow the user to somehow edit the text in the suggested action itself and then click it to send (as normal)

Are any of these possible?

Comment: For webchat :

Capture the suggested actions result in your bot
Send back an activity to webchat
Capture this activity in your activity middleware
Use the sendBoxValue hook to fill the sendbox with the selected value
The users should now be able to change the content and send if like a regular message

Comment: @Hessel Thank you. We are using the handoff feature so the suggested actions are actually for the agent on a browser (user will be communicating via sms). Is there a way to 'drop' the activity in the agent's middleware after capturing, and then use the sendBoxValue hook to fill the sendBox?

Comment: Not sure. Not familiar with the handoff feature. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/health-bot/handoff

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. Dont think my idea would work because the agent is playing the role of the bot in the scenario. If the suggested  actions are sent by the bot, you could also decide to render your own suggested actions with an onclick event filling the sendBox